# Keep an action in view post out of devise authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have installed devise gem for authentication. I have created a scaffold named Members. I have put

```html
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

at the  top of the Members controller. but I want to make

```html
Member.Show
```

action to be out of the authentication. I mean with out signing in any one can see the Members profile.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add this line in your controller (typically, at the beginning):

```
class MembersController < YourBaseController
  # ...

  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:show]

  # ...
end
```

Comment: @Deep: thanks for your comment. I usually assume that the before_filter will end up in a base controller, and every child controller may want to skip authentication in some actions.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way is to use an except filter for this:

```
class MembersController
  ...
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: :show
  ..
end
```

This way all of your logic around the filter is contained in one place. You can also pass in an array of actions to exclude:

```
class MembersController
  ...
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:show, :another_action]
  ..
end
```

For more see: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
class MembersController < ApplicationController
   skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:show]

   #rest of the codes
   def show
     #show codes
   end
end
```